# null value in init block of parent class

Tags: kotlin

I was creating a very simple kotlin program and saw a weird behavior for parent class.

The code is:

```
fun makeSalt(name:String) = Spice(name, "non-spicy")
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var salt : Spice = Spice("salt", "non-spicy")

    println("Salt heat = ${salt.heat}")

    val spicelist = listOf<Spice>(
        Spice("salt", "non-spicy"),
        Spice("turmeric", "mild"),
        Spice("Pepper", "hot"),
        Spice("Chilli", "hot"),
        Spice("Sugar", "non-spicy")
    )

    val mildSpices = spicelist.filter{it.heat <=5}

    val salt2 = makeSalt("rock salt")

    val bhoot : SubSpice = SubSpice("bhoot", "hot")
}


open class Spice(open var name:String, open var spiciness:String = "mild" ){
    var heat : Int = 5
        get() = when (spiciness){
            "mild"->5
            "hot"->10
            "non-spicy"->1
            else -> 0

        }

    init{
        if(spiciness === null) {println("spiciness is null")}
        else println("Spiciness of ${name} = ${spiciness}; heat = ${heat}")
    }
}

class SubSpice(override var name:String, override var spiciness:String = "hot") : Spice(name, spiciness){

}
```

When I execute this program, the output is:

```
Spiciness of salt = non-spicy; heat = 1
Salt heat = 1
Spiciness of salt = non-spicy; heat = 1
Spiciness of turmeric = mild; heat = 5
Spiciness of Pepper = hot; heat = 10
Spiciness of Chilli = hot; heat = 10
Spiciness of Sugar = non-spicy; heat = 1
Spiciness of rock salt = non-spicy; heat = 1
spiciness is null
```

As you can see, when I created an object of the sub-class, the variable `spiciness` of parent class becomes null. Can someone explain why is that? I expected it to be null since it also has default parameter of `"mild"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are you using `open var` when you're not overriding any getter/setter methods.

You're introducing weird initialization conflict since `Spice.init` (parent class constructor) is invoked before `SubSpice.init` and by overriding the fields they are no longer initialized alongside parent constructor - instead they will be available once `Subspice` is constructed.

Remove `open` keyword from variables in parent class and `override var` in child constructor, that way fields will be properly initialized in `Spice` class and its `init` block should run successfully.

Answer (score 2):

To add extra information to Pawel's answer:

If you are overridding properties using `open`, the init block in the base class will run before the derived properties have been initialized.

See docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#derived-class-initialization-order

So if we change the code like Pawel suggested, we end up with something like this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Spice("salt", "non-spicy")
    Spice(name="spice")
    SubSpice(name = "bhoot", spiciness = "hot")
    SubSpice(name="subspice")
}

open class Spice(var name:String, var spiciness : String = "mild" ) {
    var heat : Int = 5
        get() = when (spiciness){
            "mild"->5
            "hot"->10
            "non-spicy"->1
            else -> 0
        }

    init{
        if(spiciness === null) {println("spiciness is null")}
        else println("Spiciness of ${name} = ${spiciness}; heat = ${heat}")
    }
}

class SubSpice(name: String, spiciness : String = "hot") : Spice(name, spiciness) {
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Spiciness of salt = non-spicy; heat = 1
Spiciness of spice = mild; heat = 5
Spiciness of bhoot = hot; heat = 10
Spiciness of subspice = hot; heat = 10
```

Comment: Thanks. Since I cannot mark both of your answers as "accepted", I have marked Pawel's answer as the accepted one